# How to modify component data from async function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and can't understand how to properly use async functions inside of the components

I want to create a test component that:

- Receives a list of requests to be sent
- Executes them one by one (in async function)
- When the response is received, it appends it to the list of responses
- If all requests were successful automatically shows a modal
- If any request fails, shows a button that the user needs to click in order to show modal

Right now I managed to do this

```js
function requestReportReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'append':
            return [...state, action.payload]
    }
}

export default function RequestList(props) {
    const [report, reduceReport] = useReducer(requestReportReducer, [])
    const [hasErrors, setHasErrors] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function sendRequests() {
            for (const requestData of Object.values(props.requests)) {
                const response = await sendRequest()
                const isSuccessful = response.statusCode < 400

                reduceReport({
                    type: 'append', payload: {
                        isSuccessful: isSuccessful,
                        responseCode: response.statusCode,
                        responseBody: response.body,
                    }
                })

                if (!isSuccessful)
                    setHasErrors(true)
            }

            if (!hasErrors)
                showAllRequestsAreSentModal()
        }

        sendRequests()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
          <dl>
            {report && report.map((requestReport: RequestReport) => (
              <p>some html here</p>
            ))}
          </dl>
          {hasErrors && <button onClick={showAllRequestsAreSentModal}>Finish execution</button>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see, I want to be able to set `hasErrors` var and read it in both the async function and JSX which does not seem to work. I understand that this implementation is incorrect, but how can I fix it? I have found a lot of similar questions, but could not understand how to apply the suggestions proposed there in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just learning react, it's fine to code stuff like this yourself.

For real-work projects, I highly recommend using a wrapper around Promises.

[`@tanstack/react-query`](https://tanstack.com/query/latest) is my personal (an many other's) go-to solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this issue because it doesn't immediately update the hasErrors variable in the outer scope , for solving this issue  you can use the useEffect dependency array and update hasErrors using setHasErrors within the useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function sendRequests() {
      for (const requestData of Object.values(props.requests)) {
        const response = await sendRequest();
        const isSuccessful = response.statusCode < 400;

        reduceReport({
          type: 'append',
          payload: {
            isSuccessful: isSuccessful,
            responseCode: response.statusCode,
            responseBody: response.body,
          }
        });

        if (!isSuccessful) {
          setHasErrors(true);
        }
      }
    }

    sendRequests().then(() => {
      if (!hasErrors) {
        showAllRequestsAreSentModal();
      }
    });

    // Include 'hasErrors' in the dependency array to monitor its changes
  }, [hasErrors]);

 }
```